# Typeorm Nestjs tree repository with querybuilder. Load only one relation property

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an tree struction in my db that I load with

```js
getManager().getTreeRepository(Elements).findTrees()
```

But I want to load and select a specific relation. I want to load the `user` relation and only select the `username`. Without loading the tree structure, the right way would be like this:

```js
this.elementRepository.createQueryBuilder('element')
  .addSelect('user.username')
  .leftJoin('element.user', 'user')
  .getMany()
```

But how can I combine those two? I want to get the full tree structure but with the user relation. I don't want to load the full relation with `.findTree({ relations: ['user']})`, just the `user.username`.